# What is this electrical component on a Time Crisis II I/O PCB?

Tags: identification, components

I have a Nanco Time Crisis II That has a bad I/O board. Power is getting to the board, but not making it to the chip on the board (activity LEDs not flashing).  I’m trying to trace where there may be a problem but there are components on the board I don’t recognize.

[image: I/O PCB v185]

What is component FL1 & FL2?  They have 3 legs and the only other marking on it is 222.  How do I test it?  Can I test this in-circuit?

Comment: perhaps you already know, but no LEDs doesn't necessarily mean there is no power to the chip - it could be halted for some reason, blocked waiting for something to happen, ro simply not running. Did you check the power pins with a meter or (better) a scope?

Comment: I did check the VCC on the board there and got 5v.  I'm actually looking for the chip schematics to see if I can find VCC on the chip that the LEDs indicate activity from, but haven't had much luck yet.

Comment: @DinoGambone - Hi, Can you check whether the center pin of the unknown FLx components is connected to 0V?

Comment: @SamGibson Yes they are.

Comment: @DinoGambone - OK, thanks. Please see my comment and link below the [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/557296/101852) from *Hearth*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FL is usually the designator for a FiLter, I believe. Most likely, they're a simple filter network of some sort, probably either to filter noisy input power or to filter noisy signal lines.

Comment: That's what I've read, but I have limited experience with this and that does not look like the normal EMI filters I see (those are the much larger).  Can you test these?  Can they be tested in circuit?

Comment: @DinoGambone They may be ceramic resonators or something? They probably can't be tested in circuit, but even if you were to test them I don't know how you'd be able to be sure they're working right without using a network analyzer.

Comment: @DinoGambone - Hi, "*does not look like the normal EMI filters I see*" FYI some EMI filters can be small. See [this previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507983/which-kind-of-component-uses-an-em-symbol-prefix-has-a-value-and-three-pins) for an example of small filters. Considering the component designator on the PCB of FLx, a filter (as suggested in this answer) seems a good hypothesis to test.

Comment: Ok, that all makes sense.  Are there ratings I need to match?  I was able to find this containing the '222' markings on it: https://in.element14.com/murata/dss6ne52a222q55b/filter-emi-rfi-6a-100v-2200pf/dp/9527486

Answer (score 1):

Those are EMI filters. They are basically T filters, with two inductors in series, passing from first to third pin and a capacitor from the middle pin to the middle pin of the two inductors.

Comment: Thanks @Justme.  Do you know what the 222 marking indicates?

Comment: Depends on the manufacturer which we don't know unless you have the service manual with BOM. It might mean impedance, but it is extremely likely that 222 means the EMIFIL capacitance, which would be 2.2nF.

Comment: Ok, and last question: is there any way to test it to see if it's good or bad?

Comment: Like I explaind, it has two inductors in series and capacitor to middle pin. It should read approximately 0 ohms between pins 1 and 3, and from pin 2 infinite ohms to pins 1 or 3.